# Adding multiple modules in znd framework zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using the zf2 for developing my web application

I have multiple modules to be used in it. But when I initiate all my module in application.config.php files it will overwrite the services of 1st module with second one.

For example

In my application.config

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'ZfcAdmin',
),
```

The services of Application module is over written by the ZfcAdmin Module

I am already using different namespaces for both modules

Thanks 
Sam

Comment: How you come to know that your services are being overwritten?

Comment: I print the data of the Countrytablegateway for Application module but it is actually outputting the data of the Countrytablegateway for ZfcAdmin module. Seems like overwritting to me

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Well if your Services have the same NAME then it's obvious they are to be overwritten. All configuration will be MERGED into one big file, so make sure to either have unique Service names or to use then in the order you need.

Comment: But they all are under the different namespace and under different modules

Comment: What matters is the name inside the configuration, not the value...

Comment: Can you provide your `module.config` files for examination?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature. It's assumed that if you provide the same service from two modules that they both fulfil the same role.

This concept is one of the core strengths of ZF2. Want to over-write something built into Zend? Or a component in a 3rd party module? Give your service the same name as the one you're overwriting and you can.

To solve your problem rename Countrytablegateway in ZfcAdmin to ZfcAdminCountrytablegateway or don't give your service short (non-namespaced) names or aliases. e.g.

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'ZfcAdminCountrytablegateway' => 'ZfcAdmin\Gateway\Countrytablegateway',
    )
)
```

or

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'ZfcAdmin\Gateway\Countrytablegateway' => 'ZfcAdmin\Gateway\Countrytablegateway',
    )
)
```